# Vue ApexChart | How to implement my own custom tooltip to change the shape of the marker in the tooltip?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, linechart, apexcharts

I currently have a chart as shown in the picture. Some lines are dotted and I wanted to indicate that in the marker but right now all the markers are in the tooltip all "circle". For example, if the line is dashed then I want to show dashed line in the marker instead of a circle.

[image]

The documentation did not have anything about the marker shape so I decided to create my own custom tooltip but before I go that route, did anyone have success changing the shape of the marker?

```
  tooltip: {
                enabled: true,
                enabledOnSeries: undefined,
                shared: true,
                followCursor: false,
                intersect: false,
                inverseOrder: true,
                custom: function ({ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
                    console.log(w.config.stroke.dashArray[seriesIndex], seriesIndex, dataPointIndex);
                    return "<div>" + series + "</div>";
                }, // This is how I am trying to achieve the impossible but if there is any other way, I really appreciate it. 

                marker: {
                    show: true,
                    custom: () => {something to change the shape based on line dash Array ?}


                },
            },
```